# How to create fallback if value is not found in JSON when saving to state React

Tags: json, reactjs

This is my get request which grabs a few different JSON end points:

```
// Grabs the posts from the json url
private getPosts() {
   axios
      .get( this.getCompanyUrl() )
      .then(response =>
        response.data.map(post => ({
          id: `${ post.Id || post.jobId }`,
          name: `${ post.Name || post.advertisements[0].title.localization[0].value }`,
          name2: `${ post.Name || post.title.localization.pop().value }`, 
          //location: `${ post.Location || post.department.title.localization[0].value || 'Fall back location' }`,
        }))
      )
      .then(posts => {
        this.setState({
          posts,
          isLoading: false
        });
      })
       // Error catching
      .catch(errors => this.setState({ errors, isLoading: false }));
}
```

If a location is not found in the JSON, I want to add a fallback location, however it does not seem to be working:

```
Line 214 >> location: `${ post.Location || post.department.title.localization[0].value || 'Fall back location' }
```

I receive this error, even when there should be a fall back working:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
>     at JsonFeed.tsx:214
>     at Array.map ()
>     at JsonFeed.tsx:210

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: notice that the error states that "Cannot read property 'title' " that is happening because `post.department` is undefined, that's why it's throwing.

Comment: There is no fallback at this line `post.Name || post.title.localization.pop().value` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app supports [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) then you could do it like this:

```
post.Location || post.department?.title?.localization?[0]?.value || 'Fall back location'
```

Otherwise, you could use the old-school style:

```
post.Location ||
(
  post.department &&
  post.department.title &&
  post.department.title.localization &&
  post.department.title.localization[0] &&
  post.department.title.localization[0].value
) ||
'Fall back location'
```